# How to solve a dual LP problem with three variables?

Tags: proof-verification, linear-programming

Given the LP problem

[image]

I know that the dual will be 
[image]

I  know that the optimal value of the LP problem is 7.5 and that the values of *x1* and *x2* are respectively (0.5,3).

However I am not sure how to solve the values of the dual problem since there are three variables.

On the LP problem i found the solutions by the graphical method and equated the first constraint to the second constraint.

I am not sure I can do this with the dual since there are three variables. I have some learning disabilities and If you may explain how to get to *y1,y2,y3* in the simplest way possible it would be greatly appreciated.

On the answer sheet it states that the optimal of the dual is (7/4, 1/4 and 0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guide:

The third constraint in the primal is not active, hence the corresponding dual variable, $y_3$ must take value $0$ by complementary slackness condition.

Now having $y_3$ fixed to be $0$. It is now a $2$-variable LP and you can solve for $y_1$ and $y_2$.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your answer. May I ask you what you mean by the third constraint 'not being active'? Thaanks!

Comment: $x_1-x_2 = 0.5-3<1$, it is not equal to the right hand side. The equality doesn't hold as compared to the other two constraints.

Comment: Im sorry but 0.5-3=-2.5 which should be smaller than 1? How come the equality doesn't hold (sorry if im bothering you ).

Comment: $-2.5 \ne 1$ right? you are welcome to clarify, it takes time to learn a new topic.

Comment: THANKYOU!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!